# Load another jsp in current <div> box when (onchange) selected any <option>

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I have `load_person.jsp` with code as

```
<h3>Person's Info</h3>
Person: <select onchange="loadIntoDiv(this.value)">
<option value="1">Select Name 1</option>
<option value="2">Select Name 2</option>
<option value="3">Select Name 3</option>
</select>
<BR><BR>
<div id="fetchHere"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Proposal" />
```

Now what I want is to load a new jsp page i.e `fetch.jsp` whenever any of the option is selected. I want JavaScript Code only, NO JQUERY PLEASE.

Onchange of option, this `loadIntoDiv(this.value)` must be called and that function should call `fetch.jsp`. Please note that `fetch.jsp` must not be loaded until any of the option is selected. And should be called or loaded every OnChange, so no need to hide or show div concept needed.

I want JavaScript Code for `loadIntoDiv()` for above scenario.

Comment: why don't you do this with a form ? why you want to do it with javascript

Comment: with form, how can I do that, please tell me.

Comment: Re my comment on @Taha 's answer _"I'm J2EE web developer"_ and _"fetch.jsp should be loaded"_ — `load_person.jsp` runs on the server, and the _result_ of running is sent to the browser. You say  _"note that fetch.jsp must not be loaded until"_ : `fetch.jsp` does not get "included" (loaded) in load_person, rather, the javascript will make an AJAX request to the server and place the _results_ of whatever the server runs in the target div. "fetch" doesn't even have to be a jsp, it could be a servlet because you're not loading a page, you are just fetching data, which could be HTML, XML, or JSON.

Comment: It was a good session, thanks to all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution far ago but forgot to update, so here it is..

We need to make an AJAX call and the response of that AJAX will be `fetch.jsp` (page with some processing and data if needed) and replace the previous div content with this response.

```
function loadIntoDiv(var abc) {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("fetchHere").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/ServletController?param=abc", true);
  //Here param is used to pass the value of selected element
  //We can also use here POST/PUT/DELETE methods..with some modification.
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` runs in client side. `JSP` runs at the server side. The client and server are two diffrent environments 
I suggest that you do it with `Ajax` calls it is  an efficient way for a web application that reduces the need to do a page refresh or full page reload

for example : 
you change the select tag to

```
<select name="selection" id="dropdown">
<option value="1">Select Name 1</option>
<option value="2">Select Name 2</option>
<option value="3">Select Name 3</option>
</select>
```

and If the content of fetch.jsp  is

```
<%
   String val = request.getParameter("selection");
   out.println(val);
 %>
```

then you can add this script to load_person.jsp to get the value with ajax call :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#dropdown').on('change', function() {
        selection = $("#dropdown").val();

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "fetch.jsp",
            data : "selection=" + selection  ,
            success : function(data) {
                $("#fetchHere").html(data);
            }
        });
    });     
});
```

Comment: how will it detect that this `fetch.jsp` should be loaded only inside the `<div id="fetchHere"></div>`. The thing you are saying is redirecting to another page. I don't want a new page to be loaded. I want that new page to be loaded inside of this `<div></div>`.

Comment: you didn't say that in your question you say that function should call fetch.jsp

Comment: I already mentioned in the question title "to load inside current <div>". I think you got confused with that, sorry, but now please tell me solution with this.

Comment: I edited my answer can you paste the content of fetch.jsp ?

Comment: you can't do this with simple javascript code you should use Ajax call with JQUERY

Comment: @ManojShukla This _can_ be done with plain javascript, no jQuery, but it's going to be _much_ more complicated, because jQuery handles a lot of tedious details for you, and also handles cross-browser differences. I also have thoughts on _"I'm J2EE web developer"_ and _"fetch.jsp should be loaded"_ but that seems more suited to the question itself, so I will comment there.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what Taha's function did, but in pure javascript, without JQuery:

```
  window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById('dropdown').onChange = function() {
       selection = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
       var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("fetchHere").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
         }
       };
       xmlhttp.open("POST", "fetch.jsp", true);
       xmlhttp.send("selection=" + selection);
     }}
```